# "Perhaps I misunderstood you"

Tags: meaning

How do I say "Perhaps I misunderstood you"? Is it correct or I must say "perhaps I understand you mistakenly”?

> 1. Perhaps I misunderstood you
> 2. Perhaps I understand you mistakenly

Comment: The tone of "Perhaps I understand you mistakenly" suggests that you understood the other person, when you're actually not supposed to (_by mistake_).

Comment: How can I say it?

Comment: To "misunderstand" means to understand _something else_, as opposed to what the other person actually intended. What you actually might want to say is "Pardon me, I could not understand you" - which indicates that you understood nothing of what the other said.

Comment: _Perhaps I misunderstood you_ is perfectly fine. #2 is terrible English though, and should be avoided. However, you could say, “Perhaps I’m not understanding you,” if you want to switch to the present tense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to say this.  Your first example is perfectly fine:

> I'm sorry, perhaps I misunderstood (you).  Could you say it again?

Other examples:

> I'm not sure I understood you.
>
> I didn't get what you were saying.
>
> It's not clear what you said.
>
> I must have missed that.
>
> I didn't catch that.
>
> That *went in one ear and out the other* (idiom)

And others, plus variations.  If you want to be less polite about it, and put the blame on the other person for not saying it right:

> That made no sense / that didn't make any sense.
>
> It wasn't clear what you were trying to say

Plus others.